# I am using getElementById to get data from this API, but it is not returning anything in the table when I run it

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I run the HTML this is what shows up:[the table shows up fine but the data from the API site doesn't show up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcDVC.png)

Javascript

```js
async function fetchData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/current.json');
  const record = await res.json();
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = record.data[0].date;
  document.getElementById('positive').innerHTML = record.data[0].positive;
  document.getElementById('death').innerHTML = record.data[0].death;
  document.getElementById('deathIncrease').innerHTML =
    record.data[0].deathIncrease;
}
fetchData();
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>US Covid Cases</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-3" style="width: 450px;">
        <h2 class="text-center">US Covid Cases</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>positives</th>
                    <th>deaths</th>
                    <th>Death increase</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="date"></td>
                    <td id="positive"></td>
                    <td id="death"></td>
                    <td id="deathIncrease"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MY PATH"></script>

</html>
```

Is it a problem that the API URL ends in a .json? I am very new to this type of code. I'm not sure what is wrong in my code, is it a problem with the API website?

Comment: Yeah, the data is outdated, I just wanted some practice with using APIs. This will not be used for anything besides my practice.

Comment: The way to get the value from the response needs to be adjusted, I posted the answer, you can refer to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to print out the `record` object, you will find that the data type is an array.

```
[
  {
    ...,
    "date": 20210307,
    "positive": 28756489,
    "death": 515151,
    "deathIncrease": 842
  }
]
```

So just replace `record.data[0]` with `record[0]`

```js
async function fetchData() {
  const res = await fetch("https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/current.json");
  const record = await res.json();
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = record[0].date;
  document.getElementById("positive").innerHTML = record[0].positive;
  document.getElementById("death").innerHTML = record[0].death;
  document.getElementById("deathIncrease").innerHTML = record[0].deathIncrease;
}
fetchData();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>US Covid Cases</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-3" style="width: 450px;">
    <h2 class="text-center">US Covid Cases</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>positives</th>
          <th>deaths</th>
          <th>Death increase</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="date"></td>
          <td id="positive"></td>
          <td id="death"></td>
          <td id="deathIncrease"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```